# How can I use SQL during migration in test database (to create a foreign key)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new to rails (3.2.13) development and have not been able to find a way to do what I'm trying to do.

**Background:** I created a migration that, because there appears no other way to do this using sqlite, creates a new table in the database with a foreign key.  Specifically, I ran:

```
rails g model period_type_specs period_type_id:integer start_date:datetime end_date:datetime user:references
```

I then wanted to ensure that the period_type_specs table had a foreign key constraint (`period_type_id -> period_types(period_type_id)`).  After researching and trying a few things, the only thing I found that worked with sqlite was, in the CreatePeriodTypeSpecs migration file, replace what was there with pure SQL to create the table with the desired foreign key, using 'execute'.  This worked - that is, after `rake db:migrate`, the new table, with the needed foreign key, was created in the development database.

**Problem:** I've so far found no "kosher" way to get the same table/schema into the test database.  After the db:migrate, `rake db:test:prepare` creates the table, but with no foreign key.  I believe this is because `db:test:prepare` simply uses db/schema.rb to create the missing table and schema.rb uses the standard "create_table..." operations and (I believe) raw SQL is not supported in schema.rb.

The only way I can think of at this point to create the table as I want in the test database is to simply run the sql commands, from the migration file, directly on the test database.  But, of course, this would interfere with the goal of using rake to reset or remove and then automatically recreate the database schema.

So - is there a way to do what I want without cheating?

**Update**: I ended up putting the SQL statement to create the table with the foreign key into db/seeds.rb, which is also where the table it refers to (a static reference table) is populated.

Comment: why you want to create table in your test cases only? Is this table doesn't exists in dev db?

Comment: My intention is to create the table in both development and test.  There's no problem in development - the table is created via the migration script in db/migrate.  But the 'rake db:test:prepare' step doesn't use that script.  As I said in my post, it uses db/schema.rb, which doesn't use the SQL code in the db/migrate/*.rb file; thus the problem creating the table as I want in test.

Comment: Add that particular migration and schema.rb in ur question